# ServletContext - Application scoped session object returning null

Tags: java, session, tomcat, servlets

I am trying to put a HashMap on to the ServletContext object so that i can access it from a war file that is on a different context. I have not tried to access it from mutliple contexts yet. I just tried to access from the same servlet and i cant seem to be able to get the value. Both approaches below return nullpointerexceptions.

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -8002515227440283546L;

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws IOException{
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    HashMap<String ,String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hm.put("1", "1");

    this.getServletContext().setAttribute("usernamanager", hm);
    this.getServletConfig().getServletContext().setAttribute("usernamanager", hm);  

    HashMap newMap2 = (HashMap) this.getServletConfig().getServletContext().getAttribute("usermanager"); 
    HashMap newMap3 = (HashMap) this.getServletContext().getAttribute("usermanager"); 

    out.println("App1 - " + newMap2.get("1"));
    out.println("App1 - " + newMap3.get("1"));
}
}
```

The servlet is deployed on a Tomcat container.

Comment: The attribute names do not match..."usernamanager" and "usermanager"

Comment: You are right. Its a silly mistake from on my part. Thanks

Comment: Please post this as an answer and ill accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute names should match: `usernamanager` vs `usermanager`